# Create a Client request inside a HTTP method in Restlet

Tags: java, httprequest, restlet

Is there a way to send a client request inside a HTTP method?

For example, I have Items resource and it has POST method

```
@Post

public Representation acceptItem(Representation entity) {

    1. get information from entity

    2. create new Item

    3. setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_CREATED)

    4. send POST request of another resource (e.g. orders resource)
    ClientResource ordersResource = new ClientResource(ordersURI);
    orderResource.post(info);
}
```

code:

public class ItemsResource extends BaseResource {

```
/**
 * Handle POST requests: create a new item.
 */
@Post
public Representation acceptItem(Representation entity) {
    Representation result = null;
    // Parse the given representation and retrieve pairs of
    // "name=value" tokens.
    Form form = new Form(entity);
    String itemName = form.getFirstValue("name");
    String itemDescription = form.getFirstValue("description");

    // Register the new item if one is not already registered.
    if (!getItems().containsKey(itemName)
            && getItems().putIfAbsent(itemName,
                    new Item(itemName, itemDescription)) == null) {
        // Set the response's status and entity
        setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_CREATED);
        Representation rep = new StringRepresentation("Item created",
                MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        // Indicates where is located the new resource.
        rep.setLocationRef(getRequest().getResourceRef().getIdentifier() + "/"
                + itemName);
        result = rep;           

        //**In this POST method, send another POST request on another resource**
        ClientResource ordersResource = new ClientResource(
                "http://localhost:8111/firstResource/orders");
        ClientResource orderResource = null;

        // Create a new item
        Order order = new Order("order1", "this is an order.");
        try {
            Representation rO = ordersResource.post(getRepresentation(order));
            orderResource = new ClientResource(rO.getLocationRef());
        } catch (ResourceException e) {
            System.out.println("Error  status: " + e.getStatus());
            System.out.println("Error message: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } else { // Item is already registered.
        setStatus(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_NOT_FOUND);
        result = generateErrorRepresentation("Item " + itemName
                + " already exists.", "1");
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

So in this way, when the client send a POST request on items resource, not only he creates an Item, but also creates an order.

I tried it in my code but it caused error:

```
Sep 16, 2014 6:57:49 PM org.restlet.engine.component.ClientRouter getNext
WARNING: The protocol used by this request is not declared in the list of client connectors. (HTTP/1.1). In case you are using an instance of the Component class, check its "clients" property.
Not Found (404) - The server has not found anything matching the request URI
```

If I put these two lines(`ClientResource ordersResource = new ClientResource(ordersURI); orderResource.post(info);`) in the main method, it works. If I put them in a HTTP request, it doesn't work.

So I'm looking for a way to send a client request in a HTTP method?

Comment: Question is not clear. can you describe more and put some code what you tried till now.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I just added some code. this is the code from restlet example. i just add a client request in the POST method, so that when the client send POST request on Item, it triggers POST request on Order as well. But it causes error : "Error  status: Not Found (404) - The server has not found anything matching the request URI"

Comment: I have encountered a similar problem. Where I create a ClientResource inside a test() method on a class that extend a ServerResource. Could this be related?

I tried to create a ClientResource on a isolated project at the main() method and it works. For me it fails on the first scenario 

TL;DR ClientResource get() call inside a ServerResource class?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the below init params inside the servlet declation in the web.xml . With this your application will be able to make HTTP HTTPS and FILE protocol calls.

```
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.restlet.clients</param-name>
            <param-value>HTTP HTTPS FILE</param-value>
        </init-param>
```